# Vue.js composable axios

Tags: vue.js, composable

I'm making composables for axios. I want to allocate loading value after execute(). but i can't allocate by

I want to control loading value in axios composable file. How can I allocate the value for props?

I tried const {error, loading: loading, execute } = useAxios(); It doesn't work...

```
<template>
  <form class="ma-5">
    <h2 class="ma-2">Sign-up</h2>
    <v-text-field
        v-model="state.username"
        :error-messages="v$.username.$errors.map(e => e.$message)"
        :counter="10"
        label="Name"
        required
        @input="v$.username.$touch"
        @blur="v$.username.$touch"
    ></v-text-field>

    <v-text-field
        v-model="state.email"
        :error-messages="v$.email.$errors.map(e => e.$message)"
        label="E-mail"
        required
        @input="v$.email.$touch"
        @blur="v$.email.$touch"
    ></v-text-field>

    <v-text-field
        v-model="state.password"
        :error-messages="v$.password.$errors.map(e => e.$message)"
        label="password"
        required
        :type="show ? 'text' : 'password'"
        @input="v$.password.$touch"
        @blur="v$.password.$touch"
        :append-icon="show ? 'mdi-eye' : 'mdi-eye-off'"
        @click:append="show = !show"
    ></v-text-field>


    <v-row justify="end">
      <v-btn @click="signup">
        submit
      </v-btn>
    </v-row>

    <LoadingAlert :loading="loading"/>
  </form>

</template>

<script>
const { error, loading, execute } = useAxios(
    'v1/sign-up',
    {
      method: 'post',
    },
    {
      immediate: false,
      onSuccess: () => {
        console.log("성공");
      },
      onError: err => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
);
</script>
```

This is axios.js file

```
axios.defaults.baseURL = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_API_URL;

const defaultConfig = {
    method: 'get',
};

const defaultOptions = {
    immediate: true,
};

export const useAxios = (url, config = {}, options = {}) => {
    const response = ref(null);
    const data = ref(null);
    const error = ref(null);
    const loading = ref(false);

    const { onSuccess, onError, immediate } = {
        ...defaultOptions,
        ...options,
    };

    const execute = body => {
        data.value = null;
        error.value = null;
        loading.value = true;
        axios(unref(url), {
            ...defaultConfig,
            ...config,
            data: typeof body === 'object' ? body : {},
        })
            .then(res => {
                response.value = res;
                data.value = res.data;
                if (onSuccess) {
                    onSuccess(res);
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                error.value = err;
                if (onError) {
                    onError(err);
                }
            })
            .finally(() => {
                loading.value = false;
            });
    };
    if (immediate) execute();

    return {
        response,
        data,
        error,
        loading,
        execute,
    };
};
```

This is LoadingAlert.vue

```
<template>
  <v-row justify="center">
    <v-progress-circular
        v-if="loading"
        color="primary"
        indeterminate>

    </v-progress-circular>
  </v-row >
</template>

<script>

export default {
  props: {
    loading: Boolean,
  }

}
</script>
```

Comment: It's unclear what the problem is. "doesn't work" is not a clear description. I don't see problems with code

Comment: Think you also need to add <script setup> instead of just <script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be attempting to import and use a Vue 3 composable function right within the script tag of a Vue SFC (Single File Component), however this is not the correct way to accomplish it. In Vue 3, the setup() method is where composable functions should be used.

Here's how you may modify your Vue SFC to correctly use your useAxios composable:

```
<template>
  <!-- ... your template will go here ... -->

  <LoadingAlert :loading="state.loading"/>
</template>

<script>
import { reactive, toRefs } from 'vue';
import { useAxios } from './axios.js'; // replace './axios.js' with the actual path to your axios.js file

export default {
  setup() {
    const { response, data, error, loading, execute } = useAxios(
      'v1/sign-up',
      {
        method: 'post',
      },
      {
        immediate: false,
        onSuccess: () => {
          console.log("Success");
        },
        onError: err => {
          console.log(error.value);
          console.log(err);
        }
      }
    );

    // if you have other reactive data
    const state = reactive({
      username: '',
      email: '',
      password: '',
      loading: loading,
      // ... rest of your reactive data ...
    });

    const signup = () => {
      execute({
        username: state.username,
        email: state.email,
        password: state.password,
      });
    };

    // if you're using vue-validate
    const v$ = useVuelidate(rules, state);

    // Always return the refs, because the template uses the reactive data
    return {
      ...toRefs(state),
      v$,
      signup,
    };
  },
};
```

Please double-check the proper import of useAxios. The component's reactive state is defined by the reactive function, which is then used to transform it into a plain object with refs that can be utilized in the template more easily. Since the loading value is a component of the returned reactive state, it may be utilized directly in the component template as state.loading.

Remember that the setup function should return any methods or variables you intend to use inside your template.
Hope this helps.